# Bash commands run asynchronous when executed by cronie

Tags: shell-script

I have a bash script to backup my raspberry pi, and after running the backup command my pc is supposed to powerdown. This works when I just run the script via the command line. But when cronie executes it, it immediately jumps to the shutdown command instead of waiting for the backup to finish.

What can I do about that?

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@192.168.x.x dd if=/dev/mmvblk0 bs=1M | gzip -c > /path/to/backup/$(date -I) && systemctl poweroff
```

Comment: Are you usually authenticating your SSH connections against an SSH Agent?  This would not work in cron or cronie.

Comment: How confident are you that you actually get useful backups? ISTM that you're copying an image from a live system, so there's no guarantee whatsoever that your backup is valid.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not yet using an ssh-agent, did not know that this won't work. What about using cron to start a systemd service linked to my bash script?

Comment: @roaima I was not aware of that, maybe I should look into other methods.

Comment: `rsnapshot` is one method I use - at work and at home. `duplicity` is another.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using `ssh-agent` or are you just not aware of that? Are you using a key without a passphrase? It would be a good explanation that the SSH connection fails. `gzip` does not get any data but that is not an error for it so the `ssh | gzip` pipeline immediately exits with 0 so the system is immediately shut down. No `ssh` in the background. Put `set -o pipefail` before the `ssh` line. Does the system shut down still?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I figured it out, the problem was the ssh connection, I was running the script as root to be able to use systemctl poweroff, but running it as root doesn't work with the ssh keys. The ssh keys are passwordless by the way.

Comment: As for backup software, I have good things to say about `borgbackup` and `restic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seemed that `ssh` was running in the background. Actually `ssh` could not connect and exited at once which made `gzip` exit immediately, too. But because the exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command (unless `set -o pipefail` is used before) the shutdown command was executed.

If you want to use an SSH key which is not in the default files for the respective user then you need to tell `ssh` about the key file with the `-i` option:

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.x.x dd if=/dev/mmvblk0 bs=1M
```

Comment: I think I'm going to use rsync as it deals better with a live system. This way I can backup my PC and my Pi.

Comment: @TheDutchman Same problem with `rsync` as it uses `ssh`. However, as it seems that your problem has been solved you should consider accepting my answer so that this question does not appear as unanswered any more.